# How to pass multiple values for a column in sql Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have two tables, such as

**Queue**

```
QueueID
LogParameters
```

**QueueParameters**

```
QueueParametersID
QueueID
LogParametersKey
LogParametersValue
```

I have to write SP inorder to make an entry in both the tables,

LogParameterKey and LogParameterValue may contains multiple values but the QueueID for each values should be same and QueueParameterID could be different.

```
**QueueID**  **LogParameters**      
   1          AA        



**QueueParametersID**   **QueueID**  **LogParametersKey** **LogParametersValue**
       1                     1             FirstName             Mohammad
       2                     1             LastName               Salman
       3                     1                Age                    17
```

How do i pass multiple values for LogParameterKey and LogParameterValue?.. Someone suggested me to use Array for this... Is there's any other way?

CREATE Procedure AddQueue
@LogParameters NVARCHAR(255)
@AuditParameters AS AuditParameter READONLY,-- UserDefinedTable

AS

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN 

DECLARE @QueueID BIGINT

EXECUTE dbo.procInsertQueue
@LogParameters = @LogParameters,
@QueueID = @QueueID OUTPUT


DECLARE @GetQueueID BIGINT = (SELECT QueuesID FROM Queues WHERE LogParameters= @LogParameters
DECLARE @AuditQueueParametersID BIGINT
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(
ParameterKey NVARCHAR(255),
ParameterValue NVARCHAR(255),
AuditQueuesID BIGINT)

INSERT INTO @TempTable(ParameterKey,ParameterValue,QueuesID)
SELECT ParameterKey,ParameterValue,@GetQueueID FROM @AuditParameters

DECLARE @LogParameterKey NVARCHAR(255) = (SELECT ParameterKey FROM @TempTable WHERE QueuesID = @GetQueueID)
DECLARE @LogParameterValue NVARCHAR(255) = (SELECT ParameterValue FROM @TempTable WHERE QueuesID = @GetQueueID)

EXECUTE dbo.procAddQueueParameters
@AuditQueueID = @GetQueueID 
@LogParametersKey = @LogParametersKey,
         @LogParametersValue = @LogParametersValue,
@QueueParametersID = @QueueParametersID OUTPUT
END
```

END

Comment: Take a look at Table-Valued Parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use User-Defined Table Types**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx

**2. Generate xml string and parse in SP**

**3.Use temp table**

```
CREATE TABLE #Input
(
QueueParametersID ..
QueueID ..
LogParametersKey ..
LogParametersValue ..
)
--INSERT VALUES
EXEC dbo.YouSP
```

IN SP use table #Input